# Assembler and compiler connection?

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction

I am reading about object code (I am not asking what object code is), and became confused when encountering the following:

*When reading about assembler:

> An assembler program creates **object code** by translating combinations
>   of mnemonics and syntax for operations and addressing modes into their
>   numerical equivalents.

And when reading about [object code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_code) itself:

> In computing, object code or object module is **the product of a
>   compiler**.

However, when looking at components of the compiler, no articles that I have read really include the assembler as part of the compiler, like
[image]

So how can object code be "the product of a compiler" if the assembler program "is not part of the compiler"?

Comment: The assembler is also a compiler, just for assembly language instead of C++.

Comment: Just looking at the definitions provided, it's clear the assembler is a compiler: it outputs object code.

Comment: @MadPhysicist then how come it is usually depicted as a separate process in the language processing system, like [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=language+processing+system&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHyJzAqLfbAhUN6aQKHT4lBpYQ_AUICigB&biw=1920&bih=974#imgrc=7l6t0tPPEIKBwM:)

Comment: @nichlnss - The Code generator part could generate assembly code as output or it could generate object code directly. Many compilers have options for doing it either way.

Comment: @BoPersson okay. I see why the object code would be a product of the compiler in the latter case, but what would you say? Is the object code part of the assembler or compiler - what would be the most correct thing to say? I mean if the assembler to some is a part of the compiler and to others is not...

Comment: The assembler *is* a compiler. It provides an optional intermediate step in the compilation process.

Comment: There are phases (stages) to compiling a program.  A single compiler can combine all the stages into one program; or break it up into many programs that you run independently; or have a master program that runs all the stages for you (chaining the independent programs).  You are confusing the logical activity of compilation stages with the implementation details of actual compilers.

Comment: @RichardCritten So the logical activity of compilation always includes the assembler (if necessary)?

Comment: Object file is machine code (native to the target platform), with some extra meta data containing public symbols and information for linker about instructions that needs final addresses, etc... Whether it is generated by high level programming language compiler, or assembler doesn't matter in the end, both paths produce native machine code for target platform (unless you talk about compilers targetting some virtual machine, like Java, C# and similar). You can even produce object file manually in hexa editor, without assembler or compiler. But it would be quite tedious and error prone.

Answer (score 3):

Either:

1. The compiler produces object code directly, with no assembly phase at all, or
2. It produces assembly and then executes the assembler, in which case the assembler is indeed logically part of the compiler.

In either case, when the compiler exits, what you have is object code, ready for the linker.

NB Your picture doesn't show the linker either, but you won't get a target program without it.

Comment: Well according to the wiki article about assemblers, the object code is the product of the assembler and according to the wiki article about compilers, the object code is the product of the compiler - so if the compiler produces assembly (and executes the assembler as a separate process), then the object code would come from the assembler and not the compiler, right? I feel like I have confused it all a little too much...

Comment: I've already answered all that. I don't know what you're expecting now.

Answer (score -2):

The 'assembly source code' (pre-object code gen) is equivalent to the intermediate code or intermediate representation (IR) that gets generated by the compiler (in your diagram). It then goes through passes to optimize and produce object code native to the target machine ABI.

Whether or not the IR is used to produce object code or another IR (such as that consumable by an interpreter) is up to the compiler design and intent.

Not seeing the word 'assembler' in the diagram is trying to parse the semantics of the diagram into syntactical sugar.

Comment: No. If a compiler is going to generate assembly code it does so last, *after* the IR and the optimization and register-allocation phases.

Comment: That is not what I said. I said the IR is a form of assembly code. I know because _*my*_ compiler emits LLVM-IR which IS-A form of assembly and it gets optimized and emits machine code.

Comment: You said they are equivalent, and you went on to imply if not state that optimizations, register colouring, and so on can be applied to assembly language. It is nonsense. Assembly language is a *final* output of compilers that emit it. Not equivalent to IR.

Comment: You are wrong. Assembly is a form of source code, machine code is the final output of compilers. In LLVM-IR it is SSA assembler by their own definition. Ipso Facto "assembly code" it a form of "IR" and the same can be semantically said about any non-machine code form.